# Is it possible to use Onedrive in a batch mode without a web interface?

Tags: onedrive

Everything I'm reading shows that in order for an application to use onedrive, it has to do the oauth2 thing to get credentials. But what if you're a batch process and don't have a web interface for your users.

Google's API has a special type of account called a service account where once you set it up, you can control access to everything from that one account, no need to interact with users. Does such a thing exist for onedrive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[App-only authentication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) doesn't require the user be prompted for credentials but it also isn't supported in 100% of scenarios. For example, the APIs need a user principle for creating special folders and resolving a user's personal site. Also, it is only supported for OneDrive for Business, not Consumer. Consumer always requires the user be prompted for initial authentication.

Another option would be to spin up a web service of some sort that handles initial user authentication, ie. a sign up page. With that, you can retrieve a refresh token for offline authentication and store it for the user. Every authentication from then on can be done using the refresh tokens, which doesn't require a user prompt.

Comment: hunh. Okay. I guess I have some more reading to do. There are lots of moving parts and it's not immediately obvious to me which ones are important, and which ones are deprecated... I'll check that out, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found this. It's the same basic idea as google's service account, but I think it's harder to use. But at least the concept is supported.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/21/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx